# svmtrain compared to fitcsvm

Tags: matlab, svm

In the previously used but now deprecated [`svmtrain`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) function, the function will stop and return "No convergence error" if it couldn't train the svm successfully after a certain number of iterations.

However, I notice the newer [`fitcsvm`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) returns without any error message, even if no convergence is reached. Is there is away to force `fitcsvm` to only return if svm is successfully trained and otherwise throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported. It says in the [documentation of `fitcsvm`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) under the `IterationLimit` option:

> The software returns a trained classifier regardless of whether the optimization routine successfully converges.

So you would have to throw the error manually. Either:

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y)
if not(SVMModel.ConvergenceInfo.Converged)
    error('SVM training did not reach convergence')
end
```

Or:

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y)
assert(SVMModel.ConvergenceInfo.Converged, ...
       'SVM training did not reach convergence')
```

Comment: Thank you ... I notce SVMModel.ConvergenceInfo.Converged=0, So how can I force fitcsvm to only return when it converge successfully.